# Is there a way to log all console output to an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on an Electron app to run my discord.js bot, and I want to log any errors that may be thrown to the console into the html of a div that I made. I have it working for things like `console.log` and `console.error`, but discord.js uses `throw new Error`. Is there any way I can pull the error content from these types of errors in order for me to print it to my new "console"?

Heres the way im doing the `console.log` thing:

```
console.log = function(message) {
    document.getElementById('console-text').innerHTML += `<p class="console-output">${message}<p>`
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `error` listener to the window:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('console-text');
window.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
  const p = container.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  p.textContent = error.message;
  p.className = 'console-output';
});

throw new Error('foobar');
```

```html
<div id="console-text"></div>
```

In Node, the same thing can be done by listening for an `unhandledException` event:

```
require('process').on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
```

I recommend against doing

```
.innerHTML += `<p class="console-output">${message}<p>`
```

because this can allow for arbitrary code execution. Create the `<p>` element explicitly and assign to its `textContent` instead.